# AHK Prevent Multiple Hotkey Triggers

Tags: triggers, autohotkey, hotkeys

It's a quite simple code.
I just want my Mousewheeldown to Send P only once.
Even if I scroll it like 3 times, I only want it to send P only once every 100ms or sth.
Here is my really small bit of code so far:

```
    SetKeyDelay , -1, 50
    #NoTrayIcon
    #NoEnv
    #persistent
    #MaxMem 2

    WheelDown::
    Send {p}
    return
```

Comment: Have a look into `#MaxThreadsPerHotkey`.

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping a bit after sending the keystroke would solve this problem.

```
WheelDown:
    Send, p
    Sleep, 100
return
```

Also, you do not need to put the p between {}-s (curly braces), as it is not a special key.
The sleep command takes it's parameter as milliseconds, so if for example you would want to allow it only one 'p' in a second, you would write `Sleep, 1000`.